# SwiftUI NavigationStack How can I remove whitespace between items?

Tags: swiftui

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm seeking assistance regarding an issue I've encountered while using NavigationStack in my app development process. I'm attempting to eliminate a white space that appears between items when navigating between screens, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POkXZ.png)

This space seems to be a kind of white area that emerges when NavigationStack is employed. My question is: What exactly is this space? Is it padding or another design element? And most importantly, how can I remove this space?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue)
            
            List {
                
                Section(header: Text("My custom")) {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Clear Image Cache") {
                            print("Clear Image Cache")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Test") {
                            print("Test")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        
                    }
                }
                
                
                Section(header: Text("Notifications")) {
                    Picker("Notify Me About", selection: $notifyMeAbout) {
                        Text("Direct Messages")
                        Text("Mentions")
                        Text("Anything")
                    }
                    Toggle("Play notification sounds", isOn: $playNotificationSounds)
                    Toggle("Send read receipts", isOn: $sendReadReceipts)
                }
                Section(header: Text("User Profiles")) {
                    Picker("Profile Image Size", selection: $profileImageSize) {
                        Text("Large").tag(profileImageSize)
                        Text("Medium").tag(profileImageSize)
                        Text("Small").tag(profileImageSize)
                    }
                    Button("Clear Image Cache") {}
                }
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the content in a `VStack` with custom spacing like:

```
NavigationStack {
    VStack(spacing: 0) { //  Use this
        Text("Hello, world!")

        List {
            ,,,
```